# how to remove light effect on BABYLON Lines

Tags: lines, light, babylonjs

I try to develop a board game with BABYLON.js
I have a board and an ArcRotateCamera.
My light is an HemisphericLight

When I draw Lines on my board I would like that these line have all the same aspect.  Now when I move the camera, the light have an effect on these lines and some of them disappear by changing color too close to the background color.

How i can define that my line doesn't are affected by the light ?

Answer (score 4):

If there is no material attached to them, create a new StandardMaterial and assign it (`mesh.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial('mat', scene);`).

Once those meshes have a material, you can simply set `material.disableLighting` to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the method mentioned of excluding it from the lights (for which you can also use `light.excludedMeshes.push(mesh);`) you can try removing the glare which makes a material look metallic and too shiny. Depending on what you want, one or the other will work better.

This is how you remove the glare:

```
light.specular = new BABYLON.Color3(0,0,0);
```